# SKShapeNode disappears when updating path

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

I initially draw a line with an `SKShapeNode`.

```
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    p0 = CGPointMake(-(self.frame.size.width/2), 100.0)
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, p0.x, p0.y)
    p1 = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 100.0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, p1.x, p1.y)
    line = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    addChild(line)
```

This works fine. It draws a purple line across the screen. 
I am trying to update the path of that line in an update function that get's called 60 times a second. This curves the line based on the users finger.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, p0.x, p0.y)
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, nil, fingerLocation.x, fingerLocation.y, p1.x, p1.y)
    line.path = path
}
```

As soon as the update function runs the line disappears. I don't know if I am using the right procedure of updating the path of the `SKShapeNode`. I can't seem to find any information about how to do so. I get the `fingerLocation` from the `touchesMoved` method using `touch.locationInNode(self)`.

Comment: You're using `update:`, which will be called before each frame update. Keep in mind it won't always be called 60 times a second.

Comment: @SantaClaus Good to know. Shouldn't it still work? It would be updated at that point correct?

Comment: Possibly related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294642/sprite-kit-skshapenode-path-not-drawing-quad-curve